How to Remove encrypted(LUKS) soft RAID forcely in Linux?
I built a soft RAID0 with two SSDs(Samsung-980Pro), and encrypted it with LUKS, since I had only one PC a few years ago.
Now I bought a server, and directly disassemble one SSD from the old PC(without removing it from the soft RAID array), and attach it onto the server.
But the SSD on the new server can NOT be re-partitioned, and the other SSD on the old PC also can not be removed from the array, since the array status is inactive.
I even can NOT remove the whole RAID device from Linux, since it can not be opened with cryptsetup open.
It is a boring job to re-disassemble/re-assemble the SSD between computers, as that the SSD must be pluged under many other devices.
Is there a way, I can forcely re-initialize these two SSDs respectively on two different computers, regardless whatever they storage?
Thanks!

First of all, this is the question or the rant? Of course, you can reuse your SSDs without moving them back and forth or "opening" the LUKS container. That you lack the needed expertise and experience doesn't mean you can SCREAM OVER THE INTERNET ABOUT IT. Better ask humbly and wait for someone who can answer. And, don't forget to provide the technical details, at least, lsblk and probably blkid, that would be very helpful to see what it is we are dealing with.

RAID0 is striping.  Either you have all the disks "together" or you lose your data.  If is RAID1 (mirroring) then you should be able to start each disk independently in degraded mode.  If you just want to lose the data and reuse the disks, just stop the raid and reconfigure the disks (being careful to get the right disks!).  Note that you should be able (with some work) to network access one of the disks and assemble the raid array that way.

@NikitaKipriyanov Sorry, since English is not my native language, it is hard to descript exactly the problem. I can NOT express with appropriate tone. I have not pasted any detail information as I think this is a general question. Maybe I'm wrong or I forgot it. Thanks for your reminding!
